# how to match particular string by using python

Tags: python

I want to print the string. In my code i am not getting the right string.

```
line="\\python\001tag\file.txt"  
str=re.search(r"\[(0-9)+]",line)   (don't use raw_string here)

print str.group()
```

This gives nothing. I want to extract 001 from there.

Note: I don't want to use rawstring.because here user is getting the path from other resource. Is it possible to replace single slash by double slash to solve this problem

Comment: Please don't over-tag; your question looks specific to Python 2, so it *certainly* doesn't need the `python-3.x` tag.

Comment: so you now ask a totally different question! Open a new question, if you need a new answer.

Comment: I didnt change the question. I explained the scenario. Because i cant able to use the raw string here

Comment: do the strings always follow the same pattern?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [raw-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) so that escape sequences are not processed:

```
sat = r"\\Python\001tag\file.txt"
```

Demo:

```
>>> sat = r"\\Python\001tag\file.txt"
>>> sat
'\\\\Python\\001tag\\file.txt'
>>> print(sat)
\\Python\001tag\file.txt
>>>
```

Comment: I dont want to use raw strings here

Comment: @gokul - Then you will need to double all of your backslashes: `sat = "\\Python\\001tag\\file.txt"`.

Comment: If another person is passing the string like this "\\Python\001tag\file.txt". Here I want to search what string that person passed and in this i want to extract only the "001" number.how to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Three errors: `'\001'` gives the codepoint in octal, actually the character at codepoint 1. Use double `\\` or raw-strings.
Second: `r'\['` escapes the '[', use double `\\` instead: `r'\\[+0-9()]'` (I have rearranged the characters in the set, so that it doesn't look like a expression group.
Third: You want to look at `str.group(0)` to get the whole matched string.